# PHP code does not work

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm using Drupal 7.
I wrote the following code in a token field, but when I refresh the node page, it doesn't show anything.

```
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $s = $node->field_name['und']['0']['value'];
  echo $s;
}
```

Can you advise me what I should do?

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the quotes in `['0']` in the following line.

```
$s = $node->field_name['und']['0']['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a  debugger installed (which makes everything very nice.  Both [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/)
and [zend](http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt) play nicely with Eclipse, but I've found only xdebug works well with neabeans) then I would add in some echoing statements throughout your code.  For example, I would write:

```
print('Before If');
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
  print('Inside If');
  $nid = arg(1);
  print("nid is $nid");
  $node = node_load($nid);
  print("Loaded node.  node is $node");
  print('node->field_name is ' . print_r($node->field_name);
  $s = $node->field_name['und']['0']['value'];
  echo $s;
}
print('After If');
```

And see what the result is.  From what you've given, it's impossible to diagnose the problem, but I suspect that your array access isn't right.  The print statement above should let you see what is going on.

Another approach is to try commenting out the entirety of your code, seeing if it works, then adding lines in one at a time until the white screen comes back.  Then you know where the problem is.  If you do that WITH the print statements I've added you should have a really clear idea of what's happening.

Also, try to have a look at your apache error file.  Often php errors are recorded there.  As to where it is, it really depends on your system's configuration, but you can google for some common places for your operating system, or ask whomever set up your apache install.

Without knowing much, I would assume that your array is the problem.  Try commenting that out first.